# how i save the data into database that has been created using fetch

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

This is first picture

[image: [![This is a third picture in this i have done some calculation..]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILJ9y.png)

This is a second picture when i click the dropdown list it fetch the item and display like a table format.
This is a third picture in this i have done some calculation..

My problem is how to save that table into database because this table has been created in model page...

```
public function Op_insert($data){

      $count = count($data['name']);

    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 

$data[] =  array(

        'Stock' =>$data['Stock'][$i],
        'Rate'=>$data['Rate'][$i],
        'Amount' =>$data['Value'][$i]

      );
   }
     $this->db->insert_batch('opstock', $data); 
     }
```

this is model code..

Comment: if you want to insert multiple record from array, use insert_batch() and for single record use insert()

Comment: that i have done it comes some error

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1555

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\application\models\User_model.php
Line: 265
Function: insert_batch

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\application\controllers\TipUp_Loan.php
Line: 160
Function: Op_insert

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1136

Column count doesn't match value count at row 3

INSERT INTO `opstock` () VALUES (), (), ('','LAKSHMI CRACKER','SPARK','autobomb'), ('','1','20','12'), ('','100','100','11'), ('','100','2000','132'), ('','',''), ('100','100','1'), ('2000','100','20'), ('132','11','12')

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/Yuva/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691 database error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem with your variable name, you are using same variable for save new data that is **$data rename with "$new_data"**

```
public function Op_insert($data){

    $count = count($data['name']);

    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 

        $new_data[] =  array(
            'Stock' =>$data['Stock'][$i],
            'Rate'=>$data['Rate'][$i],
            'Amount' =>$data['Value'][$i]
          );
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('opstock', $new_data); 
}
```